# How to sort child HashMap in object

Tags: java

I need to implement sorting, but I have problems. I have class `User` and inside I have `HashMap` with address. At the moment I don't understanding how to sort child instance with `Comparator`

```
Map<String, String> address = new HashMap<>();

address.put("1", "firstAddress");
address.put("2", "secondAddress");
address.put("3", "thirdAddress");

User firstUser = new User(1, "Viktor", "0500000000", address);
User secondUser = new User(2, "Sergey", "0600000000", address);
User thirdUser = new User(3, "Vladimir", "0700000000", address);

List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

users.add(firstUser);
users.add(secondUser);
users.add(thirdUser);

List<User> sortedUser = users.stream().sorted(user -> {
    return user.getAddress() <-- How to sort address?
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

sortedUser.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Sort address based on key ? or value ?

Comment: @Stanislav Do you want to sort users by their address or you want to sort Hashmap inside the User.

Comment: @Deadpool, yes. i need sort via key

Comment: @Tarun yes. by their address

Comment: What does your `User` class look like? If you are storing addresses in a Map you may want to use a List instead?  Or if your sorting on the key, use a `TreeMap`.

Comment: Why do all the users have all the addresses associated with them?

Comment: @Stanislav can you check the answer

Comment: @Stanislav have you tried modify the User.getAddresses() method? You can sort the address list before return it from the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should sort your users by addresses (natural order).

```
    List<User> sortedUser = users.stream().sorted((user1,user2)-> 
     user1.getAddress().get(user1.getId()).compareTo(user2.getAddress().get(user2.getId()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Stanislav can you check again